# /dev/sda2 not accessible after boot up

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I've started using dual boot with windows and ubuntu. Windows and Ubuntu 20 are stored in seperate partitions on the same SSD and there is a seperate sda2 (D drive) where I store the rest of my files.

After a reboot - I cannot access shortcuts made from the sda2 with the error "Unable to find the requested file". If I go to "Other locations" and the access the sda2 form there it seems to synch and then the shortcuts work.

Does anyone have any clue on how to resolve this permanently and what is the baseline issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to add the output of the commands `lsblk` and `mount`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.

Comment: Are /dev/sda2 mounted somewhere ? Please edit your question with the content of /etc/fstab.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has both *yy* releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) and *yy.mm* releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server/Desktop), and they are different products. There is no Ubuntu 20, closest by name being Ubuntu Core 20, but do you instead mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which is a different product?

Answer (score 0):

You should automount /dev/sda2 at system startup.
You can achieve this in two ways,the GUI or terminal(edit /etc/fstab)

I'll take you through GUI

Go to Disks (gnome-disks)
Tap on /dev/sda2
Select "Additional partition options"
select "Edit mount options"

Uncheck "User session defaults"
Check "mount at system startup" and "show on user interface"

Select "Okay" and enter password when prompt.

Reboot.

Comment: Tried that out. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, logged in today, but the problem is still there.

Comment: that's all I got